# select only specific number of columns from Table - Hive

Tags: hive

How to select only specific number of columns from a table in hive. For Example, If I have Table with 50 Columns, then how Can I just select first 25 columns ? Is there any easy way to do it rather than hard coading the column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you're asking about using the order in which you defined your columns in your `CREATE TABLE` statement. No, [that's not possible](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-494) in Hive for the moment.

You could do the trick by adding a new column `COLUMN_NUMBER` and use that in your `WHERE` statements, but in that case I would really think twice of the trade off between spending some more time typing your queries and messing your whole table design by adding unnecessary columns. Apart from the fact that if you need to change your table schema in the future (for instance, by adding a new column), adapting your previous code with different column numbers would be painful.